# How to find list of tables used in stored procedure without "With (nolock)" words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have large table data and each table need to be end with the statement (nolock) at the end , please help me to find in all stored procedure.

Example:

if a store-procedure used two tables a and b and one table b doesn't end with (NOLOCK) then i need to return following details.

SP_Name,Table_name

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: understand but i am in a situation to find it now

Comment: Go to the folder where all stored procedures are versioned and check them with some search tool.

Comment: @RahulHera Why? If you had read that page, you would have seen the alternatives suggested.

Comment: @dezso : could you please explain me in detail , it will be much helpfull

Comment: What are you really going to do if you find all the procedures that miss a `NOLOCK`? Write a dynamic SQL script to update them adding `NOLOCK`? This is incredibly difficult as it requires parsing the SQL code. And what if the procedure uses dynamic SQL itself? Good luck with that.

Comment: @ypercube: it is possible to add NOLOCK statement in all the missing tables in stored procedure ?? it's will be great for me :)

Comment: There is not built-in possibility for that and I don't think there are third-party tools that can do that. Even if you manage to automatically *find* all the places in your stored procedures where tables are used without `WITH (NOLOCK)`, you will probably still have too add the hint manually. But look, the whole idea is really, *really* yucky. The article linked above is teaching you to try and avoid using NOLOCK *at all*, and here you are asking to add it *everywhere*. You should see why people are reluctant to help you.

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  Find a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: If you explained the reason behind doing what you want to do, you might get better answers than just "don't do it". It might be possible to suggest you a real solution to the real problem (if there is any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for all the store procedure names that have the `nolock` keyword:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
    WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%nolock%' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: i want to find the tables whose select statement need to be end with 'nolock'.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find all table whom has data 'nolock' !!

Comment: this does not help me

Comment: i want to find all table whom does not has data 'nolock' in stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry I never work with 'NoLock'

Comment: I think if you change `like` to `not like` you will have gave him the solution he was looking for......maybe

Comment: @ChristianBarron: The "problem" is, even a single query can use many tables, not to mention the fact that a stored procedure can have many statements – thus, many queries. If at least one table across the entire procedure uses the hint and the others don't, then `ROUTINE_DEFINITION NOT LIKE '%nolock%'` will omit that procedure.

Comment: @AndriyM: Only you understand my question properly could you please create a question of what i am asking in stackoverflow and give me the url , so that some one will help me, cause my english is not good i think so

Comment: @RahulHera: I may have understood your requirements well, but that doesn't mean I agree to help you on this problem, sorry. I don't know if you have come up with this yourself or you are doing what your boss has told you to do or you are helping a friend – in any event, adding NOLOCK everywhere is a bad idea to begin with, and being able to do that *automatically* would be even worse.