# Need to find list of tables used in stored procedure with “nolock”?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have more than 1000 Stored procedures, due to some dirty programmers they would have used 'nolock' for stored procedure tables.

Now i am facing lots and lots of issues due to this issue in daily basics.

For some reasons i cant remove all the nolock key words from SP but i need to know in which stored procedure it occurs along with table name.

Example:

Let us consider a store-procedure(sp_user) used two tables (tbl_salary) and (tbl_account) and if one table (tbl_account) end with (NOLOCK) then i need to return following details.

`**S.N    SP_Name   Table_name**
1      sp_user  tbl_account`

I don't need Stored procedure name,i know that it can be get optained using routine_definition like clause, i need the table name only.

Any help will me much appreciated...

Comment: Do you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16229493/4519059)? ;).

Comment: @shA.t : why........?

Comment: You have asked same question again..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843156/how-to-find-list-of-tables-used-in-stored-procedure-with-nolock

Comment: didn't you asked this yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843156/how-to-find-list-of-tables-used-in-stored-procedure-with-nolock  More over some days ago someone with a name similar to yours asked this and got an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757194/how-to-find-list-of-tables-used-in-stored-procedure-without-with-nolock-word

Comment: @Deepshikha:i have modified some words so that it can be easily understandable.

Comment: Why would using the `(NOLOCK)` hint make someone a 'dirty programmer'? There are valid reasons for doing so, for example when there is a need to perform dirty reads, or when you know that the data you are interested in is not going to change, and you want to perform a query without placing locks which might block other sessions. Make sure you are sure of your rationale for changing the existing code, or you may end up with someone else cursing **your** name in the future!

Comment: @EdB: I agree with you thats why i mentioned "For some reasons i cant remove all the nolock key words from SP but i need to know in which stored procedure it occurs along with table name."

Comment: I have updated my answer asked by you yesterday. Please see :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843156/how-to-find-list-of-tables-used-in-stored-procedure-with-nolock/30843446#30843446

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT name
FROM   sys.procedures
WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE '%NOLOCK%'
```

Comment: What are you trying to say..? it doesn't help me ??

Comment: This query given result of store procedure name which it use this word

Comment: Your query will not check the store procedure text,I need the table name along with the result which contains 'NOLOCK' Keyword

Comment: More detail to refer this link  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/320137/How-to-find-a-specific-string-from-stored-procedur

Answer (score 0):

try this one :-

```
Declare  @stObjToFind       Varchar(150)

Select   @stObjToFind = 'With (Nolock)'

Select   so.id
        ,so.name
        ,so.xtype
From    sysobjects As so With (Nolock)
        Join
        (
            Select  Distinct sc.id
            From    syscomments As sc With (Nolock)
            Where   sc.text Like '%' + @stObjToFind + '%'
        ) As sc0 On so.id = sc0.id
Where   so.name <> @stObjToFind
```

Comment: I need the table name along with the result which contains 'NOLOCK' Keyword

Comment: Select 
    name,
    create_date,
    modify_date
from 
    sys.sql_modules modu with (nolock)
inner join 
    sys.objects obj with (nolock) on modu.object_id = obj.object_id
where 
    name like '%text%'

Answer (score 0):

For Procedure and dependent TableName You can use this Query

```
SELECT ProcedureName,TableName FROM (
SELECT 
S1.name AS ProcedureName, S2.name AS TableName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by S1.name,S2.name ORDER BY S1.name,S2.name) AS R 
FROM sysdepends SD
INNER JOIN sysobjects S1 ON S1.id=SD.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects S2 ON S2.id=SD.depid
WHERE S1.xtype = 'P' ) X 
where R = 1
```

Comment: it will not help you to find the dynamic result set.